# _b00t_ question: how to DRAG & DROP (*move) a file in visual studio code, without wiping the git history? (i.e. git mv on drag and drop)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Presently working [`_b00t_`](https://github.com/elasticdotventures/_b00t_)

*b00t* uses config files inside a git repository for change control.

The question is how to DRAG & DROP (*move) a file in visual studio code, without wiping the git history? (i.e. git mv on drag and drop).  Is there a plugin or other mechanism for dragging and dropping does "git mv", I can't seem to find one.

Seems like a silly & useful feature that should be on by default but I haven't been able to figure it out. Do I need to build my own extension?  Thanks!

Comment: just move or rename your file (with as minimum changes as possible), commit these files (the untracked and the deleted) and it will be recorded as a file rename in the git history

Comment: that's presently how I do it, but needing to refactor applications is fairly common in iterative development so this issue comes up more frequently.  i hate losing git history arbitrarily.  VScode already knows the file is tracked so it shouldn't be a big deal to at least TRY a git mv first.